# Thread em background, quando o app está fechado

Tags: ios, swift, thread, background, apple

Como faço para executar uma Thread com a aplicação fechada?
Ou seja, para que quando o usuário ligar o dispositivo ela inicie sem que ele precise entrar na aplicação.

Comment: sera que o usuário gostaria disso? Você gostaria que um aplicativo ficasse devorando a memória e cpu do seu smartphone sem ser usado? Acho que não é, nem de longe, uma boa prática e pode levar seu aplicativo a rejeição quando o usuário perceber que ele esta causando lentidão e aquecimento do Hardware, e pode ter certeza, o usuário de app hoje em dia esta mais rigoroso e exigente e atento a estes detalhes...Não lhe aconselho a fazer isso, nem como Desenvolvedor e nem como usuário.

Comment: No android funciona dessa maneira, assim como aplicações que executam requisições http, mesmo o usuário estando ausente da aplicação esses processos continuam sendo executados...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observação: A resposta é baseada no fato de você mencionar na pergunta que quer que a aplicação execute depois do *reboot* do dispositivo.

Só há duas maneiras de se fazer isso:

1. Desenvolver para dispositivos *jailbroken*, e ficar de fora da AppStore.
2. Sua aplicação ser do tipo VoIP.

Os modos background são bastante limitados no iOS, não há tanta liberdade quanto no Android.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo de seu objetivo, voce poderia utilizar *silent notifications*. Do manual *[Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)*

> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a “silent” notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next time they open your app.